# Is it possible to make gnuplot ignore a csv row that has "N/A" instead of a number?

Tags: csv, gnuplot

I am trying to make an XY scatter plot using gnuplot from a large data set, stored in a csv. After some set up (including changing the separator to a comma) I run the command `plot '../foo.csv' using 4:8 with points`, but nothing appears on the graph. A few of the lines have "N/A" in column 4, instead of a number. How does gnuplot handle this? Do I need to specifically tell gnuplot to ignore these lines, or should I remove them from the csv prior to using gnuplot? Could this be the reason no data shows up?

An example of data in the csv is below:

```
"","Car","Manufacturer","MPG","Cylinders","Displacement","Horsepower","Weight","Acceleration","Model.Year","Origin"
"5","torino","ford",17,8,302,140,3449,10.5,70,"American"
"6","galaxie 500","ford",15,8,429,198,4341,10,70,"American"
"13","torino (sw)","ford",NA,8,351,153,4034,11,70,"American"
```

Comment: have you checked `help missing`?

Answer (score 2):

Jup, you just give the command

```
 set datafile missing 'NA'
```

However, you example dataset only has two valid points, so the autoscaling lands them on the border, where you hardly see them. `plot ... w lp ps 4` to better see them.

check `help set datafile missing` on how gnuplot exactly handles missing and invalid datapoints (with examples), and how the behaviour can be changed.

Comment: Thanks! datafile missing works great. My actual data file is pretty large, so I don't think scaling should be an issue. However, I still can't get any data to appear! I have the x and y ranges set to within the bounds of the data, so things should be appearing...

Comment: I figured out my issue! I was plotting 4:8 when I should have been doing 8:4. That clears everything up, thank you for your help